# Different font sizes in python plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

In the following plot, the font size seems to be different for x and y axis. I am not sure what is causing it. I am using the following rcParams:

```
rcParams['mathtext.default']='regular'
rcParams['axes.labelsize'] = 9
rcParams['xtick.labelsize'] = 9
rcParams['ytick.labelsize'] = 9
rcParams['legend.fontsize'] = 9
rcParams['font.family'] = 'serif'
rcParams['font.serif'] = ['Computer Modern Roman']
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 7.3, 4.2
```

and this is how I set the x axis labels:

```
labels    = [item.get_text() for item in ax.get_xticklabels()]
labels[0] = 'Col A'
labels[1] = 'Col B'
labels[2] = 'Col C'
ax.set_xticklabels(labels,rotation=0)
```

and this is how I set the y axis label:

```
ax.set_ylabel('Percentage')
```

How do I get consistent fonts in x and y axis labels?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your code to specify fontsizes,

```
fs=9
ax.set_xticklabels(labels,rotation=0, fontsize=fs)
```

and,

```
ax.set_ylabel('Percentage', fontsize=fs)
```

You can set the y-axis tick fontsizes as,

```
for tick in ax.yaxis.get_major_ticks():
    tick.label.set_fontsize(fs)
```

Good luck.

Comment: Note also that fontsize can be specified as a number that specifies the size in points as done here, or as a string ('xx-small', 'x-small', ... 'xx-large').  Search for 'fontsize' on [this page](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.text) for more info.